# Cannot install Storm on HDP 2.2 Sandbox

Tags: hadoop, sandbox, apache-storm, ambari

When I acces the ambari dashboard on the HDP 2.2 Sandbox VM from the url *http://127.0.0.1:8080/* the ambari service shows all the services with a "?" simbol, including storm. When i try to install, I cant see the install wizard link anywhere, and if I go to the url *http://127.0.0.1:8080/#/installer/step0* it returns to the dash.

In the tutorial, they just open the dashboard and everything is set up, but i'm unable to start my storm cluster.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to install anything.

On the services (or hosts) page, you should find an Actions button that lets you stop and then start all services.  Sometimes a particular service doesn't start well and you'll need to dig in to why that's happening.

Comment: Finally, what I did is to clean uninstal de oracle virtualbox, and to redownload de ova image, now is working. Thanks!